# Getting JLabel Size

Tags: java, image, jlabel

I am trying to fit the image on `JLabel` but I cannot get Width or Height. I think because jLabel1 is not instantiated. But I drawed in design panel. Anyway how can I do it?

I created `JFrame`, `JPanel` (jPanel1) and `JLabel` (jLabel1). (On the netbeans)

Here is my code:

```
public class ImageProcessing extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Image image;

    public ImageProcessing() {

        setSize(640, 480);
        setVisible(true);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("D:\\timeline.jpg");
        image = icon.getImage();
        Image newImg = image.getScaledInstance(jLabel1.getHeight(), jLabel1.getWidth(), java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon i1 = new ImageIcon(newImg);
        jLabel1 = new JLabel(i1);

        getContentPane().add(jLabel1);
}
```

Comment: If "jLabel1" was not instantiated, you would cause a null pointer exception. Perhaps log the return values from the "getHeight" and "getWidth" method calls, to confirm its height and width. A key to debugging is narrowing down and partition the problem. Printing (or otherwise find out) the value returned by those methods will help partition whether there is a problem with the set height and width, or with how you are using those returned values.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ImageProcessing extends JFrame {

    private JLabel jLabel1;
    private JPanel jPanel1;

    public ImageProcessing() {

        initComponents();
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("D:\\timeline.jpg");
        Image scaledInstance = icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(jLabel1.getWidth(), jLabel1.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon scaledIcon = new ImageIcon(scaledInstance);
        jLabel1.setIcon(scaledIcon);

        this.setSize(new Dimension(1024, 768));
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ImageProcessing();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 604, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 351, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jLabel1.setText("Label");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(139, 139, 139)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 493, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(52, 52, 52)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 226, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(144, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        
}
```

Comment: I see but I wonder, I can resize the jLabel1 in design tab and I saw the properties, for example(226x200). But why can't I get this size from source tab?

Comment: Yes I understand my problem I deleted initComponents();
but I wrote it and I can reach width or height but now this image not appear on jframe

Comment: You mean, you could get the size of this jLabel1 after you called the contructor with `new JLabel(i1)` ?

Comment: @user3005212 Therefor it is better to add more code next time, because we can help you solving your problem, but if you have more problems in other parts of your code, we cant help you with this ;)

Comment: Yes you are right but I have no other codes except created codes from netbeans.

Comment: Show your `initComponents()`. This method initializes all the `Components` which should be on your `JFrame`

Comment: Well, i tried your `initComponents()`, it works fine. I updated my answer with the current, working code. If you want to change the size of your `JLabel`, then change it programmatically in the `initComponents()` Method.

Comment: thanks it works! Also I did research to fit image to JLabel and a lot of people choose long way(graphics 2d, paint() and others). I think this is very easy and short.